# Will rm delete files currently being accessed by web-client?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, filesystems

My web-service running on `nginx` and `php` deliver's files using `X-Accel-Redirect` header to the client, if I use `rm /my/folder/*.*` how will it handle files currently being accessed/downloaded by clients?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a process starts reading from a file, it creates a filehandle attached to the inode where the file lives.

When you delete a file, you delete the link from the directory to the inode. That link will be removed immediately, so that no other process will be able to find the file.

However, as long as there is an active filehandle to the inode, the contents will still be accessible from the process using that filehandle. Once all active processes with filehandles to that inode have closed their filehandles, the space where the file has resided will be marked as empty.

You can think of a filename as a kind of symlink.

1. You have a file named `/inodes/1234`, and you symlink that to `/myapp/myfile.txt`
2. You open `/myapp/myfile.txt`. What really happens is that you open `/inodes/1234` because that is the actual file.
3. You delete the symlink `/myapp/myfile.txt`. The original file `/inodes/1234` still exist, and the process that opened it in step 2 is still reading/accessing it.
4. Another process asks for `/myapp/myfile.txt`. It doesn't exist because you deleted the symlink. (The original `/inodes/1234` still exists, of course!)
5. The second process wants to create `/myapp/myfile.txt`. The operating system creates the file `/inodes/4711` and creates a symlink to `/myapp/myfile.txt`

Of course it's slightly more complex than that, but it's a useful model in this instance.

Incidentally, this is also an answer to the question "why is my disk full even though I deleted this huge log file and there's nothing else taking up the space" - if a process was still reading from or writing to the file, you just made it invisible, you didn't actually clear it.

Comment: Say one file is being downloaded by `client1` and I delete the file-link, what will happen if my php script checks for file existence while the other client is still downloading the file? Also, will I be able to re-create the file with same name and location while `client1` download is active but the file-link is delted via `rm`?

Comment: I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @iTech: Why don't you test this yourself - it's easy to do.